# Cannot find grid fieldtype data in database

Tags: relationships, grid

I have a grid fieldtype which has a Relationship field "Select one" allowing the user to select a channel in the grid, however although the correct value is shown in the cp (shown below) I cannot find the value in the corresponding MySQL table for the grid (the other values are in the table. Any ideas?

[image: Grid relationship]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look in the `exp_relationships` table then match the `grid_field_id` along with the `grid_col_id` and `grid_row_id` columns for exactly what you are looking for.